# C# Как вернуть из свойства различные типы данных

Tags: c#, свойства

Есть свойство:

```cs
private char[] _code = new char[2];
public char[] code { get => _code; set => _code = value; }
```

Есть ли возможность при обращении возвращать не тип `char[]`, а, например, `string`?

```cs
public char[] code { get => new string(_code); set => _code = value; } //Ругается на возвращаемый тип
```

Нужно для избежания множественного дубляжа:

```cs
string str = new string(code);
```

Comment: Так нельзя, но вы же можете сделать два свойства разного типа с разным названием https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971747/accessor-with-different-set-and-get-types И вообще у любого объекта в `C#` есть метод `ToString()`, поэтому для получения строкового представления обычно специальных методов не пишут, а используют `ToString()`.

Comment: @CrazyElf По поводу `.ToString()`, для маcсивов, или как минимум Char[], метод работает не корректно.
`char[] ch = new char[] { 'A', 'B' };
Console.WriteLine(ch);
Console.WriteLine(ch + "CD");
Console.WriteLine(ch.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(new string(ch));

Console.ReadKey();`

Вот результат вывода:
_AB
System.Char[]CD
System.Char[]
AB_

При конвертировании массива через `.ToString()`, он выводит название типа переменной а не их содержимое, так что лучше создавать новую строку с передачей массива символов `new string(char[])`

Comment: Да, тут я не прав. Тут скорее `String.Join` нужно использовать, конечно.

Comment: @CrazyElf А еще лучше StringBuilder и перегрузку Append(char[]? value), если, конечно, строку нужно будет дополнить чем-то еще

Answer (score 4):

Тип свойства не обязательно должен совпадать с типом поля. У вас есть приватное поле того типа, который вам нужен для работы

```
private char[] _code = new char[2];
```

Если клиенту нужно работать с типом `string`, сделайте свойство типа `string`

```
public string Code => new string(_code);
```